# Find and Replace within a Selection in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode9

I use find and replace in selection all the time.  It is crucial to my workflow.  It seems to be gone from Xcode 9.  This was achieved by holding down the option key once the desired text was selected.  The option key would change the context of the `replace` button to `replace in selection`.  This no longer seems to be available.

Is the ability to find and replace within a selection truly gone from Xcode 9?  If not, how do I use it?

Edit: for what it's worth I posted a bug report [here](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=35494343).

Edit 2: Here is a timed screen grab with me holding down the option key.
[image]

Edit 3: My Xcode version is 9.1 (9B55), someone below with 9.2 doesn't have this problem, maybe it's been fixed in the 9.2 beta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple is aware of this issue. It is fixed in the latest Xcode 9.2 beta. Hold down the Option key; at the right of the replace field, the All button is replaced by All In Selection.

[image]

Screen shot of the About dialog, showing the working version:

[image]

Comment: Maybe they fixed it in 9.2 then?  I have 9.1.

Comment: Confirmed, fixed in 9.2 beta and works for me, thanks.