# Xcode Find And Replace Preview Missing in 9.4.1

Tags: xcode

I use 'Find and Replace' fairly regularly. It's part of my workflow. With Xcode 8 I could enter a search term and then only replace the items I wanted by choosing 'Preview'. That option seems to have disappeared in Xcode 9.4.1.

Here is a screenshot of a previous version of Xcode as I no longer have Xcode 8 installed on my system, but it's the same basic idea.

[image: Find And Replace Preview]

Now that 'Preview' is gone from my version of Xcode.

[image: Find And Replace Preview Missing]

How do I get that functionality back?

I want the ability to make sure I'm replacing the right thing, and I want to preview the edit before committing. I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254136/find-and-replace-within-a-selection-in-xcode-9), but it didn't work for me. I tried every key combination I could think of, and still no 'Preview' option. I can't imagine I'm the only one who uses this feature.

Is this feature gone from Xcode 9.4.1, or is it hidden somewhere else? Or maybe it's called something new and I don't know how to find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in Xcode 9.4.1, I just have to use the 'refactor' option from right-clicking the item from within the VC. From there, I can see a list of possible replacements and choose from there. Ah ha!

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241881/how-to-rename-the-class-name-in-swift) answer for helping point me in the right direction.