# How to replace block in all xibs files

Tags: xcode, xib

I want to replace this in all my xibs files

```
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="key" value="daily_title"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
```

to this

```
<userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="tableName" value="Localization"/>
<userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="key" value="daily_title"/>
</userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the Search/replace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489117/xcode-find-and-replace-preview-missing-in-9-4-1 ?

Comment: It's not work with xibs files :(

Comment: You can use a third party app like Visual Studio Code, SublimText, etc.